# Why an "unused variable" compilation error when ignoring the result of append?

Tags: go, compiler-errors, append, unused-variables

why if we append data in slice and not use it (variable mySlice in the program), why not throw the error message "unused variable" golang. Thankyou

#example

```
 var mySlice []string

 mySlice = append(mySlice,"halo")
```

and same behaviour with map

#example

```
var my = map[string]int{}

my["tes"]=1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Spec: Variable declarations:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations)

> Implementation restriction: A compiler may make it illegal to declare a variable inside a [function body](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_declarations) if the variable is never used.

As you can see, a compiler may or may not accept unused variables. The current Go compiler implements this by checking if the variable is read. *Reading* a variable means the variable *is* used.

The "unused variable" (or rather "declared but not used") is given by the compiler if you don't read a variable.

For example:

```
var i int
i = 3
```

Even though you are assigning a value to `i` in the above example, since it is not read, this is a compile-time error.

Appending to a slice using `append()` involves reading the slice (the slice is passed to `append()`).

Assigning a value to a map key involves reading the map value.

Same goes if you don't use `append()` but "directly" assign a value to a slice element:

```
var i = []int{0}
i[0] = 1
```

This is OK because assigning to `i[0]` involves reading the slice header to determine the (address of the) element to which we're assigning.

But if we were to assign to `i` itself like this:

```
var i = []int{0}
i = []int{1}
```

This assignment doesn't involve reading `i` so it is also a compile-time error.

If we were to use a struct for example:

```
type Point struct{ x, y int }

var p Point
p.x = 1
```

This still compiles, even though the assignment doesn't really involve reading the `p` struct. We might think of it as "identifying" the `p.x` field involves accessing the `p` variable.

This is a little bit of "gray area" and is based on opinion of the Go authors, but this is how they decided and implemented it.

Comment: Semantically `i = 3` is not much different from `my["tes"]=1` (the same is true for the OP's `append` example). If Go core dev team wanted it - they could have banned the former as well. The more fair answer would be "because they decided so".

Comment: Here https://play.golang.org/p/kMCjaTT42ob there is **no** reading of the `i` integer value, yet it's not an error. So being "read" is not formal enough either.

Comment: And a relevant piece of a spec:

"Implementation restriction: A compiler **may** make it illegal to declare a variable inside a function body if the variable is never used." (highlighting is mine).

So, it's implementation specific really.

Comment: @zerkms Yes, that's true. But your playground example: `&i` is passed to a function, so the compiler has no guarantee `i` is not read.

Comment: @zerkms I made some adjustments based on your comments.

Comment: I have re-read my comments and find it too aggressive, sorry, I didn't intend to be rude, my apologies.

Comment: @zerkms No offense taken. It helped me realize the answer needs clarification.